# Why the term 'hidden symmetry' is preferred compared to 'spontaneously broken symmetry'?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, terminology, symmetry, symmetry-breaking

The word hidden symmetry gives me the impression that the symmetry is not actually broken. Let us consider the liquid to crystalline solid transition. It is quite clear that the continuous group of translational symmetry is broken down to discrete translations. How is this a Hidden symmetry rather than [spontaneous symmetry breaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_symmetry_breaking)?

Comment: To me, "hidden symmetry" may well be a synonym of "spontaneous symmetry". What is the actual physics question here? Remember that "Why do we use this terminology?" question are [largely off-topic here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4063/50583).

Comment: @ACuriosMind I have been told that Coleman preferred the term hidden symmetry compared to spontaneous symmetry breaking. This is why I thought there must be some conceptual matter. For concreteness, I have explained what is my impression of "hidden symmetry" in the first line of my question. But if that impression is correct then the following part of the question can be reconciled with it. During liquid to solid transition, the Hamiltonian of the solid doesn't have the same symmetry as the liquid. Does it make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer in some ways the term hidden symmetry. The reason why the term hidden comes in is that the symmetry of the vacuum or ground state is restricted away from the symmetry of the Lagrangian. This is also seen in the dichotomy between what is called the false vacuum, which is the high energy vacuum with the symmetries of the Lagrangian, and the physical vacuum of lower energy that has a restricted symmetry.

The spontaneous aspect of this comes with the exact state that emerges in the breaking of symmetry, which is in a Ginsberg-Landau type of theory stochastic and not dynamical. There are theories which posit dynamical symmetry breaking, but they have largely been a "minority report."